# python IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm getting the IndexError: string index out of range. Each line in the file "document_words" ends with "-99". So i think error may be because "-99" is not converted to int. But i'm not sure. If that is the case how can i convert "-99" to int and break from the loop.

Following is my code:

```
words=open('words','r')
image=open('document_words','r')
data=open('input','a')

linecount=0

for line in image:
    if line.strip():
        linecount+=1

image.read()
image.seek(0,0)
while linecount>0:
    line1=image.readline().split()
    for entry in line1:
        num=int(entry)
        if (num<0):
            print("break from loop")
            break
        else:
            tag=words.readline()[num]
            data.write(str(tag)+' ')
    data.write('\n')
    linecount=linecount-1

data.flush()
data.close()
words.close()
image.close()
```

Comment: What line does the error state?

Comment: Error would be at this line tag=words.readline()[num]. 'words' file would be empty. Also, you have opened 'words' file in read-only mode and trying to write in it.

Comment: @Haidro: I used print statement, it reads the first line from image until -99. Then gives:
File "get.py", line 26, in <module>
tag=words.readline()[num]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @rajpy: you are coorect, that is the line i'm getting error at.
But 'words' file is not empty. And i'm not writing in 'words' file, i'm writing to 'input' file i suppose.

Comment: Well, the list does not have 100 elements

Comment: @Haidro : It has about 1000 :).

Comment: @Haidro : Seems like i'm not able to break from the loop when i read -99 from "document_words". Coz its not printing the "break from loop" statement

Comment: @naka: My mistake, you writing it to data file, thats correct.

Comment: @naka: use print len(words.readlines()) to get the total number of lines in the file 'words' and print the value of 'num' in the for loop. Also print 'line1'. With this you can debug the issue.

Comment: @rajpy Yeah i already tried to print the value 'num'. The first line in "words is" "1 2 3 4 -99". It prints 1 2 3 4 and in the next iteration(i.e.) for -99 it gives the error. Seems like its not breaking from the loop at num==-99

Comment: @rajpy number of lines in 'words' is around 400, correction

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces!

Comment: @gnibbler: i've used tabs everywhere and haven't used space at all

Comment: @naka, the code you've posted here mixes tabs and spaces. Did you copy and paste it exactly?

Comment: @gnibbler: no i didn't. on pasting directly, i wasnt getting the required indentation. So, i had to use spaces here

Comment: @gnibbler: i think tag=words.readline() is giving an empty list here. I tried to print it. That's why the error. But i'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: @gnibbler : using words.seek(0,0) just before the line tag=words.readline()[num] solves the issue. Thanks everyone for your replies :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us which line fails, but this looks like the obvious one

```
tag = words.readline()[num]
```

so `num` is outside the bounds. I don't think it is the `-99` because it should break in that case. You can add a try/except to help track it down

```
try:
    tmp = words.readline()
    tag = tmp[num]
except IndexError, e:
    print tmp, num
```

**EDIT:** Looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces for the indenting. This is a no-no unless you are using 8 character tab-stops